# Force update all the components in React@16.8.6

Tags: reactjs

I want to update all the components in my React application (no matter what is the nesting level or if there is any prop or state change).

I tried using `this.forceUpdate()` but as some of the components don't use any props or state, those and their children are not updating.
Also, I tried the solution mentioned [in the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468301/update-all-react-children-components) but this also didn't work.

App.js

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Routes />
        </div>
    );
}
```

As you can see, Routes don't take any props, so this component is not re-rendering. As a result of which, none of the components inside Routes is updating.

One way is using the store. As this is a small operation only, so I don't want to use the store for this kind of use case.

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you need to force re-render your entire application? If certain elements don't have state or props, or their state or props don't change, then why would they need to re-render anyway? What's the change that's supposed to cause the routes to re-render?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to update components on every render, you can use a `key` prop that's different every time the component renders. This will force React to unmount the previous instance of component and mount the new one with all the state and props being reset. In case of `Route` the easiest is to assign key as the current page url:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Routes key={window.location.href} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

With other components it's a bit more tricky, since you'll need to manually ensure the key is different each time.

If you would like to have more granular control over when the components are updated, you can hook the `key` prop to the state and change it `onClick`.

[This post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop) explains the approach in more detail.

Comment: Actually, all my components are underlying Route. Also, I don't want to reset state and props on refresh. I am actually changing a variable in utility which is being used by all the components. So whenever that variable changes, I need to re-render the view with the new values of that variable keeping all the other values in state and props unchanged.

Comment: Also, will the above solution change the value even if there is no route change?

Comment: It seems like you need to save that variable to the state then, if you want the components to keep track of it. In the above solution the value won't be changed if the route stays the same.

Comment: In a way that you want the changed variable not to cause complete reset when it's being change I don't see any any other option.